# Iphone/Ipad Add Image and Text to Navigation Title

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am simply trying to add an image and text to the navigationItem title.  This is what I am doing, but it only shows the image and not the title.  This seems like it would be pretty easy.

Example (

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_small_white.png"]] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.title = @"Company";
```

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280710/iphone-setting-navigation-bar-title

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By setting a custom title view, you're replacing the standard view that normally shows the title text. From the documentation for `titleView` in `UINavigationItem`:

> If you set this property to a custom title, it is displayed instead of the title.

So you need to add your own view (possibly a `UILabel`) to display your title — one way of doing this would be to add a `UILabel` and the `UIImageView` above as subviews of a container `UIView`, and set *that* as the `titleView`.

Answer (score 27):

Here is my code:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 30)]; 
UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(40, 0, 300, 30)];

title.text = NSLocalizedString(@"My Title", nil);
[title setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[title setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0]];

[title setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyLogo.png"];
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30); 
myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
myImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
myImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
myImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.1;

[myView addSubview:title];
[myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor  clearColor]];
[myView addSubview:myImageView];
self.navigationItem.titleView = myView;
```

Answer (score 4):

In **Swift 2:**

```
var myView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 30))
var title: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(40, 0, 300, 30))
title.text = "The Title"
title.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
title.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20.0)
title.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "your-image")!
var myImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
myImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
myImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
myImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.1
myView.addSubview(title)
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
myView.addSubview(myImageView)

self.navigationItem.titleView = myView
```

Related gotcha: titleView centres automatically, if this isn't the case with the above example then you're likely using a smaller screensize (eg. iPhone). Simply change the width of the UIView and UILabel from 300 to less, as suited. It'll snap back to centre when there is room.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]; // Image name with extension

self.navigationItem.titleView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];
```

This maybe the shortest way to do that.

Comment: Shortest is self.navigationItem.titleView = [UIImageView.alloc initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];