# How to access to navigationItem when I am in a view controller in tabBar?

Tags: iphone, tabbar, navigationcontroller

I have view controllers in a tabBar. And the tabBar is in navigationController.
I want to access to navigationItem when I am in a view controller in tabBar.
Usually, when I set a navigationItem's title, I used to doing this.
(if I am in a viewController)

`[ [ self navigationItem ] setTitle: @"Menu" ];`

But I am in a view controller in tabBar in navigation controller, this way doesn't work.

A view controller has a navigationItem property. But, although view controllers in tabBar 
has a navigationItem property, that doesn't work. I think that it is right logically.

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: obviously if its a view, you can consider adding a label as a subview to show title, if thats your question.

Comment: @Seongeon Hwang: My Current application is the same is yours " tabBar is in navigationController" i had to Connect the NavigationItem through an Outlet.

Comment: @Seongeon Hwang: have you considered initializing a new UINavigationItem ?

Comment: @Ahmad Kayyali What is a new UINavigationItem?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280710/iphone-setting-navigation-bar-title/5371959#5371959

Comment: @Ahmad Kayyali that doesn't work, too.

Comment: Happy to know that you have solved it, care to share ?

Comment: In viewWillAppear method in view controller, I wrote '[ [ [ self tabBarController ] navigationItem ] setTitle: @"Menu" ];' Whenever a view appear, tabBar's navigationItem's title was set. Though this way don't slide the title text on title bar (animation), it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your view controller hierarchy looks like

```
> UINavigationController
   > UITabBarController
      > CustomViewController (CVC)
```

Controllers in a tab bar controller hold a reference to this controller via the `tabBarController` property.

In `CVC`, you can access the navigation item like this: `self.tabBarController.navigationItem`.