# setting title on navigation bar not working

Tags: ios

I want to set  title to my navigation bar. I'm using

```
[self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Some Title"];
```

But, the back button title is changed not the navigation bar title.

Comment: Set `self.title = @"Some Title";`

Comment: You might want to show your code. If it's back button title that's been changed then you are probably setting the previous view controller's title.

Comment: -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Some Title"];
}

Comment: Do it in your presented view controller, not before you present a new controller.

Comment: @letsgotim did you try my answer

Comment: should I put it in -(void)viewDidLoad?

Comment: @Anonymous i tried your code. still, back button title changed.

Comment: @Anonymous I've already included your code in viewDidLoad. But, it doesn't work.

Comment: @letsgotim hey i correct my answer please check it and let me know if it is working or not

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: Setting Navigation Bar Title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280710/iphone-setting-navigation-bar-title)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the title of your UINavigationController:

```
[self.navigationController setTitle:@"Title"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this by this only navigation bar's title will change not back button's title

```
 self.navigationItem.title=@"myTitle";
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                   target:nil
                                   action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=backButton;
```

Did you implement back button like this way if not use this code

Comment: I've tried this. Still the same. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: No, I'm just pushing a view controller. The back button is already generated by the navigation controller.

Comment: ok if you want different title for both then add back button code like this. @letsgotim

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"myTitle";
```

or

in .h

```
IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navItem;
```

in .m

```
navItem.title = @"New Title";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationItem setTitle:@"Title"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your current view controller:

```
[self setTitle:@"Your Title"]
```

or set it up at previous view controller:

```
destinationViewControl.title = @"Your Title"
```