# swift ios cant change navigation bar title

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have a modal VC and I have dragged in a navigation bar using storyboard:

[image]

But now I can only change the title in storyboard and not in code. I need to be able to change it in code since the title will be dynamic.

I have tried both of these:

```
self.title = "some title"

navigationBar.topItem.title = "some title"
```

But none of them work and I dont get any warning/error either

Comment: Why do you need to change the title?

Comment: @HaydenHolligan I want the title to display the category picked in the previously VC

Comment: @user2636197 did you try solutions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280710/iphone-setting-navigation-bar-title?rq=1 ?

Comment: Is the NavBar in your storyboard linked to your VC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your NavigationBar is connected to your ViewController per Outlet, this works fine:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var navigationbar: UINavigationBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationbar.topItem!.title = "Dynamic"
    }

}
```

Comment: I can use just navigationItem.title="test" without any Outlets